# Сравнение массивов c#

Tags: c#, массивы, сравнение

У меня есть два массива, и их надо сравнить, но один из них необходимо сравнивать, начиная с 16 элемента, а второй с начала. Так вот, существует ли какая нибудь функция, либо быстрый метод для такой операции? Ибо сейчас просто переписываю в новый массив все элементы 1 массива, начиная с 16, а уже потом их сравниваю. Эта операция повторяется у меня в цикле сравнение различных хешей, поэтому быстродействие здесь как никак нужно.

```
resultArr = new byte[cleartext.Length - 16];

Array.Copy(cleartext, 16, resultArr, 0, cleartext.Length - 16);

if (resultArr.SequenceEqual(key_64bytes))
```

Comment: firstArray.Skip(16).SequenceEqual(secondArray)
метод Skip из System.Linq

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло